# BuildKit: ssh mount doesn't work in container correctly

Tags: git, ssh, docker-buildkit

So, here's the situation. I'm trying to build an image using BuildKit on Docker WSL2, providing ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host <host>                                                                                                  
  Port 22022                                                                                                                                             
  User git                                                                                                                                               
  PubkeyAuthentication yes                                                                                                                               
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa                                                                                                                             
  Ciphers +aes256-cbc
```

doing ssh key addition:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Piece of Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:10

RUN \
apt update && apt -y install git; \
mkdir /root/.ssh; \

RUN --mount=type=ssh \
ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p 22022 <host> >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p 22022 "$(getent hosts <host> | awk '{ print $1 }')" >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
git clone ssh://git@gitlab.seventest:22022/some/project.git /root/project
```

but when Docker comes to cloning - i see this:

```
Cloning into '/root/project'...
#10 0.313 Unable to negotiate with <host ip> port 22022: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes256-cbc
#10 0.313 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#10 0.313
#10 0.313 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#10 0.313 and the repository exists.
```

As you see in config - cipher is defined in ssh `config`. Also - i have `known_hosts` blank after ssh-keyscan. And before you ask - i can easily clone projects on host without these problems.

I know that i can bypass the problem with direct passing of ssh keys, but since BuildKit gives this opportunity - what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> `cipher` is defined in ssh `config`

It is. But you are not using ssh `config`.
To use what you have defined in ssh `config`, you would need to use the URL:

```
<host>:some/project.git
```

(replace `<host>` by the `Host` entry value)

And that assumes the `config` and `key` files were `COPY` first in the Dockerfile to be used by the `RUN git clone` directive.
(Unless the [`RUN --mount=type=ssh`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) does that already)